# How to secretly start a website with command pormpt

Tags: batch-file, browser, cmd, startup

Is it possible to visit a website without opening the browser or without seeing it being open?

For example if I want to open an iplogger every time I start up my Pc and then close it again so that my IP was captured without even noticing the browser being opened or closed, just in a hidden way.

Would this be possible or is there maybe another command that you can use to do this?

Comment: You should be able to log your IP without the use of an internet browser. IPconfig will display your IP, so just look for a way to route the output to a text file instead of your terminal.

Comment: i think thats as complicated as using the browser

Comment: It might be, but it would be more discreet. I don't think you'll find a web browser that will run in the background undetected.

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question and instead describe what you're doing, as opposed to this request, which seems to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) of sorts.

Comment: Removed tags from title; acronym capitalization; spelling; grammar.

Comment: Do you want your internal IP (see answer from emsimpson92) or your external IP?

Answer (score 2):

To get your external IP address you can use this code.

```
nslookup -debug myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2>NUL |findstr /C:"internet address">>myip.log
```

You have two options to run this in the background without anyone seeing it.  You can run it from a Windows Scheduled task and set it to run whether user is logged on or not.  This will force it to run in the background with no window.

You can also launch console script and applications in the background using Vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file do this. It's much simpler than you might think.

```
@echo off
ipconfig /all > IPLog.txt
```

this will save the output of your ipconfig command to IPLog.txt. Just set it to run on startup and it will log it each time you start your PC.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do this with a conscript or a power shell Web-response,  but if you’re just trying to get your up use squashmans answer.

This powershell script runs any urls you put in a text file called `urls.txt` it saves the output of the sites to a file `out.txt` and the count of errors to `Errors.txt`

```
$cur="C:\CURRENT DIRECTORY"
$contents = Get-Content $cur\urls.txt
$num=1
foreach($content in $contents){
$stat=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$content").Content
echo $stat$num |Out-File -FilePath $cur\out.txt -Append
$num=$num + 1
}
echo $error.count |Out-File -FilePath $cur\Errors.txt
```